# java.version returning surprising value

Tags: java, system-properties

I am trying to test legacy code under a different JRE than that which it was written for.  Running under Mac OS Monterey, 12.7.1.  Let's call them JRE_old and JRE_new.  To be certain which one my code is running under, I have the following statement in my inits:

```
System.err.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

I have tried `cd`ing my Terminal to `JRE_new/Contents/Home/bin`, and launching the java there on my app's jar file (`java -jar <path to the jar>`), but the version string output is that of JRE_old.

I have also tried setting `JAVA_HOME` to point to `JRE_new/Contents/Home`, and double-clicking my app (= MyApp.app), but again, JRE_old's version string is output.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?  Thank you! :-)

Comment: What happens if you run `which java`? My guess is the problem is an entry in your PATH environment variable rather than anything else.

Comment: (And possibly a system application association - it doesn't help that we don't know what operating system you're using.) When you say "double-clicking my app" do you mean the jar file, or something else?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot that this forum is not Mac-Java specific, my bad.  Have edited OP in response to your second comment.  Re your first comment, what is `which java` please?

Comment: its a linux command to find path names.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X: It's not Linux-specific. I'd expect it to be present on most Unix variants, including macOS.

Comment: How did you launch the Java executable? `java` or `./java`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, `which java` gives me `/usr/bin/java`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, see edited OP.

Comment: @JonSkeet, my PATH contains the following: `/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin`.  HomeBrew is not currently installed on my machine, I think I tried using it a while back but gave up trying to get it to work.

Comment: On some Linux systems `/usr/bin/java` is a script or symlink that finds the real java to execute. In any case it looks like you just did not run the JVM you intended to run.

Comment: Here is what my Terminal says when I go `ls -la /usr/bin`: `-rwxr-xr-x   52 root   wheel   168432   12 Oct 23:16   java` (obviously there's a bunch of other stuff in there too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat sketchy answer, but since nobody else has tried... If I’m completely wrong, I guess I’ll provoke someone to write a better answer. :-)

The usual way (I think...) to run Java on macOS is to always use `/usr/bin/java` and set `JAVA_HOME` to the version you want; there is usually no need to mess around with `PATH`. The `java` installed in `/usr/bin` is a “shim” that launches the real Java runtime.

I must confess I do not know what happens when you double-click a .jar file. It is *probably* not affected by your setting `JAVA_HOME`, because is is quite tricky to set environment variables in a way that actually affects the Finder (just editing `.*shrc` won’t do).

I know even less how a Java program packaged as an app bundle gets launched (and it probably depends on exactly how the packaging was done – I have seen different variants of this). My *guess* would be that, somewhere inside the `MyApp.app` bundle, there’s in `Info.plist` property list file that controls the Java version to use.

The current working directory (i.e, where you’re `cd`:d to) when you invoke `java` has no effect on which implementation gets chosen. (Unless you have `.` in your `PATH`, but you haven’t — good!).

So, my recommendation would be

- Don’t put any exotic Java stuff in `PATH` (and it seems like you haven’t — good!).
- Set `JAVA_HOME`.
- Run `java -jar /Path/to/the/app/foo.jar`

Comment: Perfect!  Many thanks Ture :-)  I didn't realise that the machine was ignoring my working directory setting.  I'm getting expected results by using your bullet points.  I get those same results when invoking `java` of the two JREs with the absolute path.